# Z-index for jumbotron Text parrallax

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Working on the container scrolling over the jumbotron however the text in the jumbotron is not hiding underneath the container beneath it on scroll. How do I get 'Main Title Goes Here', 'Subtitle' and the blue box with those elements to go under the container with lorem ipsum text. Tried setting z-index to -1 for the hero-text class but it hides the text and box all together.

https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/JrwKbN

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="hero-text">
                <h1 class="hero-title">Main Title Will</h1>
                <h1 class="hero-title">Go Here</h1>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE</div>

                <div class="arrow animated bounce">
                <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END JUMBOTRON -->
<main>
<!-- MESSAGE -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">



        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-box">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is....?

Answer (score 0):

The structure looks a little confusing, but if you dont want to rebuild the html you can add something like:

```
main {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -32px;
    padding-top: 32px;
}
```